# Facebook Graph API does not return the event picture

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Edit: Seems like Facebook finally fixed this bug!

---

Could you help me understand why this is happening:

This is a public event with a picture:
https://www.facebook.com/events/282054218538223

But when I try to access http://graph.facebook.com/282054218538223/picture, all I get is a default picture.

---

Here is another public event: http://www.facebook.com/events/266496120103339

But this time, accessing http://graph.facebook.com/266496120103339/picture returns the event photo.

---

What's the difference between the 2 events?

Comment: There is a difference! First one has delimiter between "<Events" and "Join" and the second one doesn't! Really weird!

Comment: Haha, I had not noticed that ;)

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am trying to get the images of an event and it works great with the event provided in the documentation,but when i try with my own event, it returns an empty data set..

Comment: Nope, I still don't know what's going on...

Comment: I am having this same issue. Can someone on facebook if they are looking at it answer this!! More example - working https://graph.facebook.com/430779326938945/picture ; Not working -https://graph.facebook.com/271148229633674/picture

Comment: We should maybe post a bug report on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Actually, there's already one... https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/262648820496801

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer doesn't explain *why* the request doesn't work using Graph API but might help someone who needs to to retrieve event profile images.

With FQL you can retrieve the event profile image like this:

SELECT pic, pic_small, pic_big FROM event WHERE eid=282054218538223

using the event id from Robin's first example. This call returns urls to the event profile image in 3 different sizes. It works for both examples in Robin's question, just change the event id.

Try it in [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) with Robin's example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT pic,pic_big,pic_small FROM event WHERE eid=282054218538223
```

and MoXplod's example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT pic,pic_big,pic_small FROM event WHERE eid=271148229633674
```

Make sure you have access token if needed as outlined in the [FQL event table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/).

Comment: Not sure why this got selected as the answer - the answer is it's a current bug with the Graph API - this is a workaround.

Comment: So basically there is no real answer to the question. We just have to wait for facebook to fix this bug. Gunnar offered a good workaround as you said, and that's as close as you can get to an answer imo.

Comment: Note that "As of August 8 2016, FQL will no longer be available and cannot be queried"

Answer (score 3):

having the same problem. it appears to indeed be a bug with the Facebook Graph API.

I currently count at least three separate open bug-reports on the [Facebook Developers Bugs](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs) page that describe and reproduce the problem (you may need to be logged into FB to access the information) :

[Cannot retreive picture of newly created events via Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/318569924873280)

[Some event covers not available via Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/334421566619692)

[Event picture is not accessible via API](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/262648820496801)

fwiw, it might be a good idea to subscribe to all three (duplicate) bug-reports.

Answer (score 1):

I was fighting with this problem this evening. The docs are saying to use picture but what I found exploring fields is this one:

```
{event-id}/?fields=cover
```

which finally returns:

```
{
  "cover": {
    "offset_x": 99,
    "offset_y": 50,
    "source": "{url}",
    "id": "{id}"
  },
  "id": "{id}"
}
```

Comment: this worked like charm, thanks. It would be helpful if you provide source documentation link too.