# Access Facebook event photos

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use the [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API) to access images posted to the Events wall. I tried using the example event from the developers guide with the API explorer by querying `331218348435/photos`, and then I get an array of photos back.

But when I replace the ID with the one of my own event, it returns an empty data set. If I remove `/photo`, I get information about the event. The event is public and has two images posted to the wall. Why does it return an empty data set? The ID of my event is `328289597226043`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a bug, take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031905/facebook-graph-api-does-not-return-the-event-picture) which looks like similar issue.

I've tried to create one event for myself and tried to experiment with images but I don't seem to get any photos out of it.